# iframe designMode in firefox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

I create iframe with designMode=on.

When I open web site in IE and move mouse cursor on iframe, the mouse cursor get changes into text-cursor (big letter I).

But when I open web site in Firefox, the corsur doesn't change and stays arrow-point cursor.

How to fix that?

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        designer('content');

        function designer(editor) {
            var browser = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            isIE = (browser.indexOf("msie") != -1);

            document.writeln('<iframe id="' + editor + '"  width="600px" height="600px"></iframe>');


            var edit = document.getElementById(editor).contentWindow.document;                                
            edit.designMode = "On";

            if (!isIE) {
                document.getElementById(content).contentDocument.designMode = "on";
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this page](http://www.mozilla.org/editor/ie2midas.html) will help?

Comment: Why not? It should tell you everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try CSS, that should switch the cursor for you. 

iframe{cursor:crosshair} //all iframes on page
or
#content{cursor:crosshair} //just the element with the id "content"
```

Question? where is the variable **content** set in the call:  document.getElementById(content).contentDocument.designMode = "on";

Do you mean **editor** as in: var edit = document.getElementById(editor).contentWindow.document;

Okay, I see your problem, link to http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/viewsource/2003/midas/01/example2-index.html has the same issue and that's the Mozilla way.

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
if (!isIE) {
  document.getElementById(content).contentDocument.designMode = "on";
}
```

Should almost certainly read:

```
if (!isIE) {
  document.getElementById(editor).contentWindow.document = "on";
}
```

As it stands you're asking non-IE browser to find an element with id `null`, rather than an element with id `'content'`.

However, that won't get you a text caret in your IFrame, even if it does make it editable.

The best I could come up with was:

```
  document.getElementById(editor).contentWindow.document.style.cursor = "text";
```

Which turns the cursor into a caret **on the first line** of the iFrame (i.e. at the top), presumably because that's the only editable bit at that point.

Comment: Then you'd need to either supply more in the IFrame to fill it out, or settle for the fact that this is not how Firefox works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this property when the iframe `loads`.

```
var edit = document.getElementById(editor).contentWindow.document;

edit.addEventListener("load", function() {
    edit.designMode = "On";
}, false);
```